# Nested aggregation via join, figures still inflated

Tags: sql, sql-server, aggregation

I am playing with the Northwind database to avoid chasm/fan trap issues when aggregating multiple measures. I am trying to use pre-aggregated joins instead of union all.

Às a test, I am aggregating the amount of products in stock, and the amount of orders. Both of course with proper non - inflated aggregations, but I end up with inflated figures once I put everything together.

Just retrieving the amount of orders:

```
SELECT          S.SupplierID,
                S.Country,
                sum(OD.Quantity) as OrderDetailsQuantity
FROM [Order Details] OD

JOIN [Products] P ON P.ProductID = OD.ProductID
JOIN [Suppliers] S ON S.SupplierID = P.SupplierID 

WHERE P.SupplierID = 1

GROUP BY S.SupplierID,S.Country
ORDER BY S.SupplierID ASC


SupplierID  Country         OrderDetailsQuantity
----------- --------------- --------------------
1           UK              2213
```

Just retrieving the amount of products in stock:

```
SELECT P.ProductID, P.SupplierID, sum(P.UnitsInStock) as ProductsUnitsInStock 
FROM [Products] P
WHERE SupplierID = 1
GROUP BY P.ProductID, P.SupplierID

ProductID   SupplierID  ProductsUnitsInStock
----------- ----------- --------------------
1           1           39
2           1           17
3           1           13
```

So we are looking at a total expected result of 69 products in stock and 2213 orders for SupplierId = 1. Now, I first do a quick check and this looks pretty fine.

```
SELECT          S.SupplierID,
                S.Country,
                sum(OD.Quantity) AS OrderDetailsQuantity,               
                test123.ProductsUnitsInStock

FROM [Order Details] OD,
    (   SELECT P.ProductID, P.SupplierID, sum(P.UnitsInStock) ProductsUnitsInStock 
        FROM Products P
        GROUP BY P.ProductID, P.SupplierID) as test123

INNER JOIN Suppliers S ON S.SupplierID = test123.SupplierID -- filter aggregation results
WHERE OD.ProductID = test123.ProductID -- filter aggregation results
AND test123.SupplierID = 1

GROUP BY S.SupplierID, S.Country, test123.ProductsUnitsInStock
ORDER BY S.SupplierID ASC

SupplierID  Country         OrderDetailsQuantity ProductsUnitsInStock
----------- --------------- -------------------- --------------------
1           UK              328                  13
1           UK              1057                 17
1           UK              828                  39
```

But now I want to aggregate the ProductsUnitsInStock, and it just fails, ending up with 2386 products in stock. Where did I go wrong?

```
SELECT          S.SupplierID,
                S.Country,
                sum(OD.Quantity) AS OrderDetailsQuantity,               
                sum(test123.ProductsUnitsInStock) AS ProductsUnitsInStock

FROM [Order Details] OD,
    (   SELECT P.ProductID, P.SupplierID, sum(P.UnitsInStock) ProductsUnitsInStock 
        FROM Products P
        GROUP BY P.ProductID, P.SupplierID) as test123

INNER JOIN Suppliers S ON S.SupplierID = test123.SupplierID -- filter aggregation results
WHERE OD.ProductID = test123.ProductID -- filter aggregation results
AND test123.SupplierID = 1

GROUP BY S.SupplierID, S.Country
ORDER BY S.SupplierID ASC

SupplierID  Country         OrderDetailsQuantity ProductsUnitsInStock
----------- --------------- -------------------- --------------------
1           UK              2213                 2386
```

**UPDATE CSteve, just moves the issue into the aggregated join due to the 1:N relation on Order Details:**

```
with
p_cte as (
        select p.ProductID, p.SupplierID, s.Country, sum(p.UnitsInStock) as ProductsUnitsInStock 
        from Products p
        join Suppliers s on p.SupplierID = s.SupplierID
        group by p.ProductID, p.SupplierID, s.Country
        ),
oi_cte as (
        SELECT OD.ProductID, P.SupplierID, s.Country, sum(OD.Quantity) AS OrderDetailsQuantity        
        FROM [Order Details] OD   
        join Products P on P.ProductID = OD.ProductID
        join Suppliers S on P.SupplierID = P.SupplierID
        GROUP BY OD.ProductID, P.SupplierID, s.Country
        )

select coalesce(p.SupplierID, oi.SupplierID) SupplierID,
       coalesce(p.Country, oi.Country) Country,
       sum(oi.OrderDetailsQuantity) OrderDetailsQuantity,
       sum(p.ProductsUnitsInStock) ProductsUnitsInStock
from p_cte p
full join oi_cte oi on p.ProductID=oi.ProductID
                            and p.SupplierID=oi.SupplierID
                            and p.Country = oi.Country 
group by coalesce(p.SupplierID, oi.SupplierID),
         coalesce(p.Country, oi.Country)
order by coalesce(p.SupplierID, oi.SupplierID);
```

Comment: When it comes to writing readable code table aliases are essential.  Please use relevant and brief table aliases

Comment: Why do you switch the the *old* ANSI-89 JOIN syntax for your latter queries? Also, I really do suggest reconsidering the name of the object `[Order Details]`. Try to ensure that you give object's names that don't require delimit identifying. Some (poorly written) applications don't properly quote their object names and thus have problems with such objects.

Comment: As for where you went wrong, apart from reverting back to the ANSI-89 JOIN syntax, I *think* what you actually want to do if *not* `SUM` the column `[Order Details].[Quantity]` in your outer query and instead put it in the `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. The tables names - with spaces - are defined in the Northwind database and I didn't gave too much attention to using ANSI-92.

I actually want to SUM the quantity column, and not put it in the GROUP BY because I need the aggregation. Not the individual results. 

I actually did that in the 3rd query to see if the results would come back correctly. It is just the final SUM in the 4th query that provides a strange result.

Comment: I updated the code with aliases, hope this helps you guys read it better.

Answer (score 1):

If I read it correctly you're looking to summarize the products in stock and orders by SupplerID and Country.  In the CTE's in the code below I also included the ProductID in the summaries (but left out of the final SELECT).  Since it seems possible some items are in stock for which there are no sales and vice versa (can't rule it out) the query uses FULL JOIN and then the SUM aggregate function ignores the NULLs.  Something like this

```
with
p_cte as (
    select p.ProductID, p.SupplierID, s.Country, 
           sum(p.UnitsInStock) as ProductsUnitsInStock 
    from Products p
         join Suppliers s on p.SupplierID=s.SupplierID
    group by p.ProductID, p.SupplierID, s.Country),
oi_cte as (
    select oi.ProductID, oi.SupplierID, s.Country,
           sum(oi.Quantity) as OrderDetailsQuantity
    from [Order Details] oi
         join Suppliers s on oi.SupplierID = s.SupplierID)
select coalesce(p.SupplierID, oi.SupplierID) SupplierID,
       coalesce(p.Country, oi.Country) Country,
       sum(oi.OrderDetailsQuantity) OrderDetailsQuantity,
       sum(p.ProductsUnitsInStock) ProductsUnitsInStock
from p_cte p
     full join oi_cte oi on p.ProductID=oi.ProductID
                            and p.SupplierID=oi.SupplierID
                            and p.Country = oi.Country 
group by coalesce(p.SupplierID, oi.SupplierID),
         coalesce(p.Country, oi.Country)
order by coalesce(p.SupplierID, oi.SupplierID);
```

Comment: Thanks SteveC, checking this one out now. Will come back with the results.

Comment: Unfortunately, the challenge just shifts. In order to get the Supplier information I have to join via the Order Details, as a result I just introduce another 1:N inside the aggregation.

The end result is still having inflated figures. I updated my post with the new query, modified it a bit.

Comment: It seems there are instances where there is more than 1 supplier per product.  How can a supplier be allocated to ordered parts?

Comment: A supplier can deliver multiple products, but a product can only have one supplier.  I am just using the Northwind database (from Microsoft) for testing purposes, basically what I am trying to end up is a best practice for these kind of situations that I can generate via C#.  It's part of a larger proof of concept in which users pick measures, dimensions and slices and we want to generate the SQL code to get a resultset we can visualize.

Comment: Northwind is not installed on any of my instances,  If there is only 1 suppler per product I'm not seeing the cause of the row inflation.  Regarding a best practice for these situations it's backwards imo to generate SQL via C#.  My projects use high speed filters in C# to eliminate custom code associated with running stored procedures.  Put it this way, if you create parameterized procedures which accept JSON as input and return JSON as output, then with .NET Core you can pretty much eliminate all procedure specific C# code and short circuit the HTTP pipeline

Comment: The context is runtime generated SQL, based on any schema. So we generate all JOINS dynamically by traversing all primary and secondary keys, and we need to generate all aggregation statements also dynamically.

So perhaps this provides a bit more context why we are testing with a Northwind database. We just want to do a bit of pathfinding on the best way to move forward handling these types of situations.

Comment: The client which produces the user pick measures, dimensions, and slices easily produces and consumes JSON?  No schema means spaghetti code in the long run and my cynicism comes from experience :)

Comment: Didn't say its easy but it can be done. Looker and Thoughtspot use similar approaches.

Comment: Those are commercial products.  Can't see their code.  One open source project that uses a similar approach is Hangfire.  We've been running it in Beta for a few months and it's very impressive.  It creates it's own schema and installs everything you need.  Then the queries are generated dynamically at runtime.  [Hangfire](https://github.com/HangfireIO/Hangfire) check out the source code

Comment: Back to the question, is the full join necessary?  Do you have the pattern you need?

Comment: No. I have a working condition but struggling to come to a standard best practice when automating input. Manual construction is easy peasy. I will get there with a few extra colas and some nights with a bag of chips.

Comment: Well I'm eager to pass a points barrier and I'm very close.  Is there anything I could do to get this over the line?